# D3.js linear regression

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linear-regression

I searched for some help on building linear regression and found some examples here:
 
[nonlinear regression function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590922/how-can-i-use-d3-js-to-create-a-trend-exponential-regression-line)
and also some js libraries that should cover this, but unfortunately I wasn't able to make them work properly:
[simple-statistics.js](http://macwright.org/simple-statistics/docs/simple_statistics.html#section-19) and this one: [regression.js](https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js)
With `regression.js` I was able to get the `m` and `b` values for the line, so I could use `y = m*x + b` to plot the line that followed the linear regression of my graph, but couldn't apply those values to the line generator, the code I tried is the following:

```
d3.csv("typeStatsTom.csv", function (error, dataset) {
//Here I plot other stuff, setup the x & y scale correctly etc. 
//Then to plot the line:

        var data = [x.domain(), y.domain()];
        var result = regression('linear', data);
        console.log(result)
        console.log(result.equation[0]);
        var linereg = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function (d) { return x(d.Ascendenti); })
                        .y(function (d) { return y((result.equation[0] * d.Ascendenti) + result.equation[1]); });
        var reglinepath = svg.append("path")
                            .attr("class", "line")
                            .attr("d", linereg(dataset))
                            .attr("fill", "none")
                            .attr("stroke", "#386cb0")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 1 + "px");
```

The values of result are the following in the console:

```
    Object
      equation: Array[2]
        0: 1.8909425770308126
        1: 0.042557422969139225
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array[0]
      points: Array[2]
      string: "y = 1.89x + 0.04"
      __proto__: Object
```

From what I can tell in the console I should have set up the `x` and `y` values correctly, but of course the path in the resulting svg is not shown (but drawn), so I don't know what to do anymore. 
Any help is really really appreciated, even a solution involving the `simple.statistics.js` library would be helpful! 
Thanks!

Comment: the regression.js loaded from github gives error in jsfiddle so it doesn't work unfortunately, here's the file in my dropbox tho:
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37967455/lunghezza_ascendenti-xheight_regressione.html

Comment: It looks like you're explicitly calling the various generators everywhere.  I'm not sure whether it has anything to do with the problems you're having, but it would probably be helpful to spend some time learning idiomatic D3.  Rather than explicitly calling `linereg` on your data, bind the data to a selection and then let D3 take care of calling the generators.  For more information about selections check out Mike Bostock's tutorial [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/).

Comment: if you are referring to the part with d3.select("#elenco2") and such it's because I had to make it updated with the .on("change" and that was the only way I could make it work. What I tried with 'linereg' was to set up the function 'y=m*x+b' with the line generator of d3. My problem and question is in fact on how to set up the line generator to plot a line that gets the data from 'result'.<br>
EDIT: in my keyboard I don't have the correct ' to make the code, sorry

Comment: A side note: There are a number of places you can make your D3 simpler (and debugging easier - you can inspect data in the DOM!) by taking advantage of data binding: lines 115-118 (can use generic line generator), the mouseover handler on lines 140-159, and as you mentioned the change handler starting on line 295.  You can pass in numbers to D3's methods rather than manually appending `"px"` everywhere.

You can also hack GitHub includes by removing the "." between "raw" and "github" in the URL ;-)

Comment: hey, thanks for that input, but as I'm not really a coder I wouldn't know how to improve that to make more simple the lines you highlighted... I know that probably there are many redundant lines and such, but unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work otherwise, my coding knowledge is limited to plain html and css and a bit of d3.js so it's already an accomplishment not having strange error warnings in the console :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made it work using the following code found **[here](http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/06/compute-linear-regressions-in-javascript/)**:

```
   function linearRegression(y,x){

        var lr = {};
        var n = y.length;
        var sum_x = 0;
        var sum_y = 0;
        var sum_xy = 0;
        var sum_xx = 0;
        var sum_yy = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

            sum_x += x[i];
            sum_y += y[i];
            sum_xy += (x[i]*y[i]);
            sum_xx += (x[i]*x[i]);
            sum_yy += (y[i]*y[i]);
        } 

        lr['slope'] = (n * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y) / (n*sum_xx - sum_x * sum_x);
        lr['intercept'] = (sum_y - lr.slope * sum_x)/n;
        lr['r2'] = Math.pow((n*sum_xy - sum_x*sum_y)/Math.sqrt((n*sum_xx-sum_x*sum_x)*(n*sum_yy-sum_y*sum_y)),2);

        return lr;

};

var yval = dataset.map(function (d) { return parseFloat(d.xHeight); });
var xval = dataset.map(function (d) { return parseFloat(d.Ascendenti); });


var lr = linearRegression(yval,xval);
// now you have:
// lr.slope
// lr.intercept
// lr.r2
console.log(lr);
```

And then plotting a line with:

```
var max = d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d.OvershootingSuperiore; });
var myLine = svg.append("svg:line")
            .attr("x1", x(0))
            .attr("y1", y(lr.intercept))
            .attr("x2", x(max))
            .attr("y2", y( (max * lr.slope) + lr.intercept ))
            .style("stroke", "black");
```

Using the code I found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/mnUWA/15/)**

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like your path is getting drawn, just way off the screen.

[image: path element in firebug]

Perhaps the regression is calculated incorrectly?  The problem may be on line 202:

```
var data = [x.domain(), y.domain()];
var result = regression('linear', data);
```

If the raw data looks like `[[1, 500], [2, 300]]` this will find the linear regression of `[[1, 2], [300, 500]` which probably isn't what you want.

I'm guessing what you'd like to do is compute the regression with the entire set of data points rather than with the graph's bounds.  Then rather than charting this line for every data value, you want to just plot the endpoints.

Comment: yeah what you pointed out is correct, and was in fact what I was asking :)
the domain I used is the extreme values of the data I'm using for the circles, and I thought that if I have those two points the line would be generated anyways

by the way I used this line to get it:
https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js#linear-regression-

I also tried using:

var assex = [dataset.map(function (d) { return d.Ascendenti; })];
var assey = [dataset.map(function (d) { return d.xHeight; })];

but this way I'm not able to get the array needed since it needs to be [[x0,y0],[x1,y1]..[xn,yn]]

Comment: leave the last part of code, I tried making an array containing the values of each point like so:

var coord = dataset.map(function (d) { return [d.Ascendenti + ", " + d.xHeight]; });

and this in fact returns an array of arrays containing each couple of x and y values, but the console log of the var result logs NaN so I don't really know what to do now, I'm kind of lost

Comment: Why are you doing string concatenation?  Your code snipped should work fine if you just return the array of two elements rather than turning them into a string: `var coord = dataset.map(function (d) { return [d.Ascendenti, d.xHeight]; });`

Comment: ok I managed to get the interceptor & slope values, the problem was that the values were added in the arrays as strings and not values, so I added parseFloat in front of the values. I also used this http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/06/compute-linear-regressions-in-javascript/