# Linear regression with time series data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series, trend

I am trying to draw a visualization showing some trend over time.

In my line plot, I have date as the X variable, some other number as the Y variable. I used d3.time scale for x and d3.linear scale for Y. The line plot is fine.

Then I tried to draw a linear regression line, but I failed, because the data for x is not numerical. I searched and searched. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507536/d3-js-linear-regression)  has a nice adaptable regression code, but that's for numerical data; [this post](http://bl.ocks.org/benvandyke/8459843) has a graph similar to what I'm shooting, but it uses ordinal scale. I am wondering if there is any simpler way to make the linear regression code reusable for my time series data (e.g., "09-Mar-2016"). Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about javascript, but I am quite familiar with this problem.  One solution: convert those date-times into units from a known date-time, whether seconds, or hours, or days.
If your dataset supports it, take the max and min of your date-times, and subtract the min from each. If you are just stuck with text, you may have to parse the values and do your own calendar math.  However, there must be a library to handle this.