# Loosen spine, smooth line in D3js

Tags: d3.js

I want to smooth a line in D3js. I started with this:
[image: image1]

After looking through the documentation, I added interpolate("basis") - I also tried all the other options. Basis is a good start.

[image: image2]

But I want to loosen the curve even more...abstract it away from it's data points to see the general spine formation. Like so:

[image: image3]

By removing data points I can force a smoother line, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? An existing method that I might be able to take advantage of. Any ideas?

My code is pretty standard, so I didn't provide it here. Let me know if you need something more.

Comment: It sounds like you want to fit a regression line to your data and then plot that. D3 doesn't provide any functions for that. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507536/d3-js-linear-regression) may help.

Comment: No idea how to help but this question looks related maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590922/how-can-i-use-d3-js-to-create-a-trend-exponential-regression-line

Comment: You could use the Exponential Moving average to smooth out the data. If you post your code and dataset I could give you an example.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this... [d3-regression](https://github.com/harrystevens/d3-regression#regressionLoess) helps with such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I found this psuedocode to be a great place to start for line smoothing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Here is an existing js library achieving a similar goal: http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/